# Display logo before GUI of main project displayed 

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.5

I need to display my logo before the GUI of the main project is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 6, take a look at:
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/splashscreen/